# Co-occurence matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have huge data set, sample is below, and i need to compute the co-occurence matrix of the skill column, please refer to the sample data below, i read about the co-occurance matrix, and CountVectorizer from scikit learn shed light, i wrote the below code, but i am confused about how to see the results. If anyone can, then please help me, please find the sample data, and my tried code below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["1000074", "6284 6295"],["75634786", "4044 4714 5789 6076 6077 6079 6082 6168 6229"],["75635714","4092 4420 4430 4437 4651"]], columns=['people_id', 'skills_id'])

count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1),lowercase= False)
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df1['skills_id'])
Xc = (X_counts.T * X_counts)
Xc.setdiag(0)
print(Xc.todense())
```

I am pretty new to this terminology of co-occurence matrix with numbers, word-to-word co-occurence i can understand, but how toread and understand the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you may think of it just like a word-to-word co-occurrence matrix. Here, assuming your `skill` column is that 2nd column with numbers of size 4, it first looks at all unique possible values :

```
>>> count_vect.get_feature_names()

['4044',
 '4092',
 '4420',
 '4430',
 '4437',
 '4651',
 '4714',
 '5789',
 '6076',
 '6077',
 '6079',
 '6082',
 '6168',
 '6229',
 '6284',
 '6295']
```

That's an array of size 16 which represents the 16 different *words* that were found in your `skill` column. Indeed, `sklearn.text.CountVectorizer()` finds the words by splitting your strings using space delimiter.

The final matrix you see using `print(Xc.todense())` is just the co-occurrence matrix for these 16 *words*. That's why it is of size `(16,16)`

To make it clearer (please forgive the columns alignment formatting), you could look at :

```
>> pd.DataFrame(Xc.todense(), 
    columns=count_vect.get_feature_names(), 
    index=count_vect.get_feature_names())

      4044 4092 4420 ...
4044    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
4092    0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4420    0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4430    0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4437    0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4651    0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4714    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
5789    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
6076    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
6077    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0
6079    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
6082    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
6168    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
6229    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
6284    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
6295    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

**tl;dr** In that case, as you input strings, whether they are numbers (e.g. `"23"`) or nouns (e.g. `"cat"`) doesn't change anything. The co-occurrence still displays binary values representing whether a given *token* is found with another one. The default *tokenizer* for *CountVectorizer()* is just splitting on spaces.

What exactly would you have expected differently with numbers ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Arnaud, you made it so easy, i have been breaking my head till now, thank you so much, there is one thing though I would like to ask you, please bare with me, a student only, how to use the Xc.todense() results, lets say, in a table way, where i can have the feature_names(skill) and the count in a better visual. If this is a stupid ques, please bare with me. Thanks again @Arnaud

Comment: My pleasure ! About having something more visual, please check my answer edit. The only thing to do is put that in a `pd.DataFrame` again and pass in index & column names. Please confirm if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, just for knowledge, what if i want to see the result like 3 column dataframe?     Like columns names be :  skillid1   skillid2    count

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, just for knowledge, what if i want to see the result like 3 column dataframe?     Like columns names be :  skillid1   skillid2    count

Comment: @krits that's maybe worth a new question "from cooccurrence matrix to edges list" :) I'll be happy to help there.

Comment: i know, it will get tricky, that is why i asked you, well, as you said, i have placed another question with the same title, please do respond, your help is breaking the ice in front of me to walk.